# Winter 16 canvas iframe behavior change

Tags: visualforce, force.com, canvas, winter16

We have Winter 16 preview sandbox and can see that Canvas App is rendered now as iframe in iframe (there is outer and inner iframes now). Before this release there was just one iframe. For now I'm not sure if issue below is caused by changes in canvas rendering behavior, but are these changes described anywhere since I can't locate it in Release Notes?

We also use parent.postMessage(message, targetOrigin) function on canvas page to fire some js functions in parent window that contains canvas and use "targetOrigin" parameter of canvas signed request. Now, in Winter 16 postMessage fails with "Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://cs11.salesforce.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://c.cs11.visual.force.com').". It means that "targetOrigin" parameter of canvas signed request is pointing to "https://cs11.salesforce.com" in Winter 16, however in Summer 15 release where there are no iframe in iframe "targetOrigin" parameter of canvas signed request is pointing to correct URL - 'https://c.cs11.visual.force.com'. Is it some kind of SF issue passing incorrect targetOrigin in canvas signed request in Winter 16?

Thanks

Comment: did you find a solution for this? we're experiencing similar problem.

Comment: for now we're communicating SF support to clarify the details

Comment: Seems like there are lots of Canvas issues with winter release https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000TL1NAAW

Comment: having the same issue since na1 was updated this weekend with winter'16 none of our sforce interactions seems to be working.

Comment: the problem seems to be with the winter'16 adding an additional iframe for canvas apps. the parent.postMessage only refers to the parent iframe now. per-winter'16  it references the parent window you want to post messages to. you'll notice window.parent.window.parent.postMessage works

Comment: window.parent.window.parent.postMessage won't work because targetOrigin has not correct value - not the URL of page that holds canvas, but URL of outer iframe

Comment: Update from SF: introduction of new iframe is "as designed" behavior (related to Lightning Experience and Salesforce 1) that was just missed in release notes document (at least the fact it affects Salesforce classic). Waiting for clarifications about  "targetOrigin" behavior change - it's not clear for now if it's also "as designed" behavior that is not described in release notes or an issue that will be fixed (now targetOrigin is referencing outer iframe, not visualforce page that contains canvas - it can't be used for cross domain communication with visualforce page).

Comment: Victor, have you heard anything more from SF regarding the change in value of targetOrigin, was this an intended change? We have a case with SF but the response has been slow.

Comment: Hi Ronnie, they responded that it was intended change and works as designed, though they also said that created internal doc issue to update release notes documentation regarding these changes (no deadline for this - I guess after release that will be right in time :) ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to SF response introduction of inner and outer iframes as well as change in "targetOrigin" behavior are intended features and it works as designed. They are also going to update Release Notes with these changes but have not pointed the exact date.

Comment: I've just recieved the same response. Is it possible to get the value of the "targetOrigin" as it used to be? We are relying on it to build the URL to a VisualForce page from within our Canvas App.